# read file with similar csv name

Tags: r

I have the following example file in a folder. I'd like to read files having similar name.
If I use `list.files(pattern="ABC_.*?\\.csv")` ,it would read all the `csv` file. What should I change so that it reads only `ABC_001.csv` and `ABC_012` and similarly the other two.

```
ABC_001.csv
ABC_001_def.csv
ABC_012.csv
ABC_012_def.csv
```

Comment: Change the `pattern` to `pattern = '^ABC_0\\d{2}\\.csv$'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `pattern` that matches 'ABC' at the start (`^`) of the string followed by `_`, then a `0` and two digits (`\\d{2}`) followed by `.` (escape the `\\.` as `.` is a metacharacter that matches any character) and the 'csv' at the end (`$`) of the string

```
list.files(pattern = '^ABC_0\\d{2}\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
```

If it is 3 digits and not specific to 0 i.e. if we need to match 'ABC_135.csv', remove the `0` and use `\\d{3}` i.e. 3 digit

```
list.files(pattern = '^ABC_\\d{3}\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
```

---

It can be checked with `grep`

```
v1 <- c("ABC_001.csv", "ABC_001_def.csv", "ABC_012.csv", "ABC_012_def.csv")
grep('^ABC_0\\d{2}\\.csv$', v1, value = TRUE)
#[1] "ABC_001.csv" "ABC_012.csv"
```

Comment: perfect. thanks so much akrun for detailed answer :)